# How to automatically Click Button via WebBrowser

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

The Html code of my click page is :

```
<tr>
    <td style="width:140px;height:25%;padding-top:7px;padding-bottom:15px;">
    <a id="aaab.ClockInCompView.P10" ct="B" st="" href="javascript:void(0);" class="urBtnStd" ocl="return me.h_e(event,window,this,'Button','BUTTONCLICK',{'Id':'aaab.InClockCompView.P10'},'',true);" onkeydown="return me.h_m(event,window,'ur_Button_keypress(SSR.event)');" onclick="return me.h_m(event,window,'ur_Button_click(SSR.event)');" style="width:140px;text-align:center;overflow:visible;width:140px;" he>Clock-In</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I tried this code for clicking:

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("aaab.InClockCompView.P10").InvokeMember("click");
```

but this not found the button. is it possible to click this type of button via code using the webbrowser control?

Comment: You have a typo, you are missing Clock in your GetElementById call this line 'GetElementById("aaab.InCompView.P10")' should be GetElementById("aaab.ClockInCompView.P10")

Comment: Thanks, i amended that, and it generates A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in browser.exe. Maybe there is no click method?

Comment: Use view source to ensure the rendered buttoned ID is exactly as you are using it

Comment: yes confirmed element is aaab.ClockInCompView.P10, if page is made up of iframes could the webrowser1 control be looking in the wrong frame?